# Android: How get error of Media Player and use it?

Tags: android, media-player, surfaceview

I use `SurfaceView` for video player

If in stream not load video , in `logcat` view error `info(701,0)`

How get `info(701,0)` and use it ?

> Sample :

```
if(error == 701){
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you could use `setOnErrorListener(..)` to your VideoView and handle the errors there. Here is an example:

```
    mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

                    switch(what){

                        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
                            // handle MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN, optionally handle extras
                            handleExtras(extra);
                            break;

                        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
                            // handle MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED, optionally handle extras
                            handleExtras(extra);
                            break;
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            });

...

    private void handleExtras(int extra){
            switch(extra){
                case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_IO:
                    // handle MEDIA_ERROR_IO
                    break;
                case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_MALFORMED:
                    // handle MEDIA_ERROR_MALFORMED
                    break;
                case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED:
                    // handle MEDIA_ERROR_UNSPECIFIED
                    break;
                case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_TIMED_OUT:
                    // handle MEDIA_ERROR_TIMED_OUT
                    break;

            }
        }
```

Edit: 701 is an info and not an error, so to handle info you need to attach an info listener `setInfoListener()`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnInfoListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener)

and follow the same pattern as the error listener. Here is an example:

```
mVideoView.setOnInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

                switch(what){
                    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START:
                        // handle info 701 here, MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START corresponds to 701
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Note that this requires a minimum API of 17. And a reference to what you are looking for:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START

Hope this was useful.