# Play next song oncompletion

Tags: android, listener, android-mediaplayer

So the problem i have is when i drag my seekbar to the end of the song, it works from some songs and i goes to the next one, but sometimes it skips a song and stops playing.
example;

Im at song "position 1" which is passed from my mainactivity to my songactivity when a song is clicked which is displayed in a recyclerview.

And when i drag my seekbar to the end, it goes to 2 and then 3 and 4, but then it skips to 6, so it didn't play the song at position 5.

This only occurs when i drag my seekbar to the end of a song, with my next and previous button it works.

**This the code from my songActivity**

```
mCurrentIndex = (int) b.get("songIndex");

    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        mBtnPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_pause_white);
        updateProgressBar();
    }

    tvSongListSize.setText((songIndex + 1) + "/" + songList.size());

    mBtnShuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isShuffle){
                isShuffle = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                mBtnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_shuffle);
            }else{
                isShuffle = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mBtnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_shuffle_on);
                isRepeat = false;
                mBtnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_repeat);
            }
        }
    });

    mBtnRepeat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isRepeat){
                isRepeat = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mBtnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_repeat);
            }else{
                isRepeat = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mBtnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_repeat_on);
                isShuffle = false;
                mBtnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_shuffle);
            }
        }
    });


    mBtnPlayPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                        mBtnPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_play);
                    } else {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        mBtnPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_pause_white);
                    }
                    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mBtnPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_play);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    mBtnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            nextSong();
        }
    });

    mBtnPrev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           prevSong();
        }
    });
}

private void playSongNumber(int index) {
    try{
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(songList.get(index).getData());
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });

        seekBar.setProgress(0);
        seekBar.setMax(100);

        updateProgressBar();

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void nextSong(){
        mCurrentIndex++;
        mCurrentIndex %= songList.size();
        playSongNumber(mCurrentIndex);
        mBtnPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_pause_white);
        tvSongListSize.setText((mCurrentIndex + 1) + "/" + songList.size());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Clicked position: " + mCurrentIndex + " " +  songList.get(mCurrentIndex).getData(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

private void prevSong(){
    mCurrentIndex = mCurrentIndex > 0 ? mCurrentIndex - 1 : songList.size() - 1;
    playSongNumber(mCurrentIndex);
    mBtnPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_pause_white);
    tvSongListSize.setText((mCurrentIndex + 1) + "/" + songList.size());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Clicked position: " + mCurrentIndex + " " +  songList.get(mCurrentIndex).getData(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if (isRepeat){
        playSongNumber(mCurrentIndex);
    }else if(isShuffle){
        Random random = new Random();
        mCurrentIndex  = random.nextInt((songList.size() - 1) + 1);
        tvSongListSize.setText((mCurrentIndex + 1) + "/" + songList.size());
        playSongNumber(mCurrentIndex);
    }else if (mCurrentIndex < songList.size()-1){
        nextSong();
        tvSongListSize.setText((mCurrentIndex + 1) + "/" + songList.size());
    }else{
        playSongNumber(0);
        tvSongListSize.setText((1) + "/" + songList.size());
    }
}

public void updateProgressBar(){
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTime, 100);
}

private Runnable mUpdateTime = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long songCurrentTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        long songTotalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();

        tvSongCurrentTime.setText(""+utilities.msToTimer(songCurrentTime));
        tvSongTotalTime.setText(""+utilities.msToTimer(songTotalTime));

        int progress = (int)(utilities.getProgressPercentage(songCurrentTime, songTotalTime));
        seekBar.setProgress(progress);

        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};
```

A toast also show that it skips a song (toast showing 2 times).

**Second problem**  **SOLVED**

When i click on a song, it goes to the songActivity and the next song plays when onCompletion is called, but when i press the pause button, and then play again and after the song is completed it gets stuck and doesn't play the next song.

**Third problem**

When i go to the last song in my list and let it play out so OnCompletion is called, it goes back to the first song in my list, which is good, but when i then click the previous button to go back to the last song, it skips the last song.
Example:  Last song is at position [25], when completed it goes back to the song at position [0] (my first song), but when i click the back button it goes to [24] and skips [25] ( the last song).

This only occurs when oncompletion is called.

Comment: The error is in my onCompletion, but i don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because some error is happening on runtime and You haven't implemented `OnErrorListener`.

In the android documentation it is mentioned that if you don't implement `OnErrorListener` on the `MediaPlayer` object then on occurence of any error it would cause the `OnCompletionListener` to be called.

So implement an 'OnErrorListener' and return true if error has been handled and false if it is not. Returning false will again call the `OnCompletionListener`.

You can refer the android docs here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html

EDIT: One main problem that i've found in your code is that you are calling `updateProgressBar()` inside `playSongNumber()` method but it will be executed before `onPrepared` gets called. That's what causing you problem. Move your `updateProgressBar()` call inside `onPrepared` and after `mp.start()`

Comment: Ok, so i implemented the OnErrorListener, but what do i add inside that methode?

Comment: The problem still persists, when a song has ended it skips one song.

Comment: Ok, when an error occurs my mediaplayer stops playing now, how can i get rid of the error and keep my mediaplayer playing the next song without skipping a song?

Comment: you get ur mediaPlayer object, int what  and int extra `onError`. Use them to check what kind of error you are getting and based on that either you can decide to resume your playback and return true or if error is something that can't be resolved return false to skip current song.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please check it. Mark the answer accepted if it helped.

Comment: Ok, it's not skipping anymore, but for the error it show for what: -38 and for extra it show 0, what does that mean?

Comment: I'm sorry, i dont know about all the error codes. But here is what you can do to handle them https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893949/android-how-get-error-of-media-player-and-use-it

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, the problem is solved, it's not skipping songs anymore, but can you check my second problem? I added it in my post

Comment: You are again implementing the `mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener()`  inside your playPauseButton click listener. Remove it, it is simply replacing your already implemented `onCompletion` method.

Comment: Yeah i know stupid mistake, thanks for the help sir.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160886/discussion-between-rahul-kumar-and-vince).

Answer (score 0):

In my oncompletionlistener, I put my void playNext, to play next song, then I call go, to start the mediaplayer, this is how I go to next song, I put oncompletionlistener inside my method, to play new song, eg. reset, prepare, method, by calling player, I do this, and my mediaplayer advances to the next song, example below, hope I helped. Also below is how I shuffle songs, in oncompletion, and shuffle code, put musicsrv.setshuffle in your main activity class, and then button to use shuffle on off.

```
musicSrv.setShuffle(); 
  public void setShuffle(){
            if(shuffle) shuffle=false;
            else shuffle=true;
            //metadata();
            //playbackstate();
            //nots(context);
    }







  player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            if (currrentsongindex == +1) {
                                    mp.release();
                                    mp = null;     // either set counter to 0 and start again or call end of list
                                    mp.start();
                                

                                    
                            } else {

                                    playNext();
                                    go();
                                    
                            }
                    }
            });
```